# rewritemap not matching

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite, rewritemap

I'm having trouble with my rewritemap not matching things:

```
RewriteMap map txt:rewritemaps\map.txt  [NC]
RewriteCond ${map:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  ${map:$1}   [NC, R=301]
```

The map has about 4,500 entries, including:

```
arctic  /Destinations/Polar-Regions/The-Arctic.aspx
```

My RewriteLog, set to level 9, logs:

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /arctic
Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\ISAPI Rewrite\httpd.conf
Htaccess process request C:\Websites\Path\WebSite\.htaccess
[..]
applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'arctic'
map lookup FAILED: map=map[txt] key=arctic
RewriteCond: input='NOT_FOUND' pattern='NOT_FOUND' =>
```

It works with pages not in the map - eg /Contact-Us.aspx, but not with stuff which should match (such as arctic). I've tried changing location of the [NC] flag, removing the RewriteCond and renaming the map file (just in case 'map' was a reserved keyword). No joy. It also doesn't seem to be a permissions problem.

FYI, I'm using ISAPIRewrite by Helicontech as I'm on IIS6.

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

1. Try using a forward slash (/) as the directory separator.
2. If that doesn't work, try a fully-qualified path.
3. Try it without the RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

If map.txt is in the same folder with .htaccess, please try the following definition:

```
RewriteMap map txt:map.txt  [NC]
```

If it's in another location, please try to use fully-qualified path.

Also please consider updating to the latest build of ISAPI_Rewrite if you are not on it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it with "", try:

```
RewriteMap map "txt:rewritemaps\map.txt"  [NC]
RewriteCond ${map:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND [NC]
RewriteRule "^(.+)$"  "${map:$1}"   [NC, R=301]
```